# How to write a class interface which allows for std::vector-like initialization

Tags: c++, templates

Let's say I have a class `DArray`:

```
template<class T>
class DArray
{
public:
  size_t size{};
  T *data{};
};
```

and I'd like to be able to initialize it in the following ways:

```
DArray<int> myDynamicIntArray1{};
DArray<int> myDynamicIntArray2{1,2,3,4,5};
DArray<int> myDynamicIntArray3 = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

What constructors/operator overloads would I need to implement to allow for such use?

(I'm not super worried about the memory management questions and decisions that come with implementing a robust dynamic array; mainly concerned about the necessary interface signatures)

Comment: You likely want a constructor that takes `std::initializer_list`, like constructor (10) [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector)

Comment: Study the source code of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). The answer is there. Be aware of the [C++ rule of five](https://cpppatterns.com/patterns/rule-of-five.html)

Comment: Your question could use some clarification. There are several ways to write constructors that could deal with your example code.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch That seems like overkill to me :)

Comment: @cigien: then, write your own answer. I'll upvote it

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I think the dupe covers it nicely.

Comment: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/EM7f93